# Unable to Start Karaf as service on a macOS

Tags: macos, apache-karaf, karaf

I have installed karaf as a service in macOS by giving the service a custom name. After installing the karaf service, I am not able to start the service.

What I am trying to do is, install karaf as service on a Mac by giving the service a custom name. I am following the documentation from the following link https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-3.0.x/wrapper. I was able to install karaf as service but what I am not able to  do is to start or stop karaf service using the service created. This is working fine in Ubuntu and windows machines, but, on a Mac I was not able to achieve it.

FYI: If the karaf service is installed using the default name (i.e without giving any name parameters), I was able to successfully start and stop the service.

Below is the command which I used to create custom karaf service name

```
wrapper:install -n <custom-name>
```

The expected result is that, after the karaf service is installed, I should be able to load and start it on a Mac. But, I was not able to start the karaf.

The command I am using to start the karaf is

```
launchctl start org.apache.karaf.<custom-name>
```

Comment: Please use `Mac` for an Apple computer, and `MAC` for `Media Access Control` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address Similarly, Apple refers to its operating system as `macOS`

Comment: Did you work out what the issue was?  I am having something similar, when I run `./karaf debug` from the `bin` dir, it hangs just showing `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005`. Does not run to show that Karaf is starting up.